# remove first child  element in xml

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I created one xml file. i need to remove the child1 element
i m using vb.net

```
<root>
     <child1> 
         <grandchild2 /> 
         <grandchild3 />
     </child1>
     <child2 />
     <child3 />
</root>
```

anybody helpme

Comment: If it's xml, it has only one root.  Some code and data samples would help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: That is, if it's *valid* XML, it only has one root. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML you could use this approach:

```
Dim xdoc = XDocument.Load("your-file-here.xml")
xdoc.Root.Element("child1").Remove()
Console.WriteLine(xdoc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT, it's:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*/*[not(self::child1)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```